# Invisible for traceroute with iptables rule?

Tags: iptables, networking

Can someone explain me why when i set on my host iptables rule like this:

`iptables -I PREROUTING -t mangle   -j TTL  --ttl-inc 1`

... it will be invisible for `traceroute` from this moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`traceroute` ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute)) works by repeatedly increasing the `TTL` header of a packet. This header limits the amounts of hops a packet is allowed to traverse before an error is reported, which in turn gives traceroute the information about one hop. If you do this repeatedly, you will get the complete path to the target, but if a host cheats this by adding to the `TTL`, it will be just overlooked by this mechanism.